# Python reveal letters one by one where rest is dots and spaces are spaces

Tags: python, list, python-re

I am making a word guesser (for Discord) and I have this function (I did it differently before but got some help in a previous question):

```py
def hidden_word(self, keyword, counter=0):
    hidden = len(keyword) - counter
    dots = '.' * hidden
    return keyword[:counter] + dots
```

This takes the to be guessed word (called keyword) and the amount of letters to reveal (counter) for example if the keyword is "test" and the counter was 2, the function would return "te.."

Though if the keyword would consist of multiple words, for example "test word" (with counter 2), the function would return "te......." the problem here is that it is unclear whether the keyword consists of multiple words.

My ideal output would be "te.. ...."

After some research I thought this could be easily solved with `re.sub`, like this:

```py
# this function is called every x seconds
helpword = [re.sub(r'\S', '.', keyword)] # Returns "te.. ...." but not easily modifiable
helpword[counter] = keyword[counter] # Replace a dot with the following letter in the keyword
```

Gives: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment, so that doesn't work.

How could I do this?

p.s my full code [is here](https://mystb.in/FlexibleBearVip.python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a new string by replacing letters conditionally by dots:

```
def hidden_word(self, keyword, counter=0):
    hidden = len(keyword) - counter
    dots = '.' * hidden

    # use the letter if its positionally before counter OR if its a space
    # else use a dot
    return ''.join(c if (i<counter or c==' ') else '.' for i,c in enumerate(keyword))


for c in range(11):
    print(hidden_word("","house boat",c))
```

Output:

```
..... ....
h.... ....
ho... ....
hou.. ....
hous. ....
house ....
house .... 
house b...
house bo..
house boa.
house boat
```

Answer (score 1):

hello the code is not very beautiful but it works

```
def hidden_word( keyword, counter=0):
    first_word = keyword.split(' ')[0]
    end=first_word[:counter]+"."*(len(first_word)-counter)+" "+" ".join(["."*len(i) for 
i in keyword.split(' ')[1:]])
    return end 


hidden_word("hello world !",2)
```

Comment: Your answer worked almost exactly as inteded as well: the only problem is that it will not reveal any more letters after the space

Answer (score 1):

Using re.sub was good thinking, you just needed some formatting.

```
import re
def hidden_word(keyword, counter=0):
    dots = re.sub("[^\s]", '.', keyword[counter:])
    return keyword[:counter] + dots

hidden_word('test_word', counter=2)
```

[^\s] = a regexp where whitespaces are ignored, allowing you to replace every character by a dot, but keep whitespaces

EDIT: my solution isn't perfect because putting the counter to 5 won't reveal the 5th letter, I'll try to update my post with a correct solution